# Windows partitions not appearing on GRUB and on ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

for some reason my boot-loader stopped working and I had to use the recovery disc utility to restore grub.

After reinstalling grub, the windows partitions doesn't appear anymore (on grub and on ubuntu).

I tried to boot an windows installation cd to recover windows, and make some backups, and it says the i cant do that because the disk is locked (whatever that means).

Any help would be much appreciated.

the result of gdisk -l /dev/sda is:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DE3382C7-BEC6-4E8D-9E5B-BA230F20056B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   8300  EFI System 
   2         1050624      1237592063   589.6 GiB   8300  
   3      1237592064      1237624831   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft 
   4      1237624832      1945298943   337.4 GiB   EF00  Basic data 
   5      1945298944      1953523711   3.9 GiB     8200
```

And here's a screenshot of gparted (the windows partition is highlighted):
[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6sGf.png)

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Do `sudo update-grub` and see if that works.

Comment: will do! ill report in a minute

Comment: Ok, it found a windows recovery partition: `Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda4
done
`

Comment: Ok, i successfully booted windows, but it gives me an error. I tried to restore the windows bootloader to repair windows, but no good, windows is corrupted, and I have no grub now :( – Afonso Muralha 6 mins ago    
     
And the worst is that boot repair disk gives me an error: GPT detected. Please create a BIOS........ – Afonso Muralha 5 mins ago

Comment: It sounds like your best bet right now is to just reinstall. Are you willing to do that?

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. And yes, I think I'll do that... Backing up files right now

Comment: STOP. You have a UEFI install, but if Boot-Repair wants you to add a bios_grub partition that is for a BIOS boot. UEFI and BIOS are not compatible and you have to boot only from UEFI menu. Boot Boot-Repair in UEFI mode from UEFI and reinstall grub. Then you should be able to boot both Ubuntu & Windows in UEFI mode, unless you left Windows fast start up on. Then you can only boot from UEFI.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I managed to reinstall windows and boot the repair disc. I have grub, I have Windows, and I didn't loose Ubuntu (thank God)

Comment: Afonso, you may have dodged a bullet. To further elaborate on oldfred's point, *please* read [this page of mine,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) which describes the problem with the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which has apparently caused at least some of your problem. Chances are you should disable the CSM in your firmware to prevent future problems related to it.

Comment: Thanks, ill have a look. Everything is working now, I changed the bios settings from CSM to EFI.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this guide more than once, works every time.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Try this if

```
sudo update-grub
```

does not work.

Comment: I tried boot repair, but no luck until now, i did update-grub and ill report again in a few minutes (see comments)

Comment: This is not the same as repair disk, did you look at the link?
Some of the steps includes update grub...

Comment: Ok, i successfully booted windows, but it gives me an error. I tried to restore  the windows bootloader to repair windows, but no good, windows is corrupted, and I have no grub now :(

Comment: And the worst is that boot repair disk gives me an error: GPT detected. Please create a BIOS........

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable 'Fast Boot' in Windows.  For information on how to do this, please see http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

This is a good guide for Windows 10, and googling can get you instructions for other Windows versions.

Comment: I can't boot windows

Comment: That's not going to help if Windows is the OS not booting.

Comment: You should be able to boot Windows from the BIOS boot menu.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was solved by reinstalling windows and restoring grub after.

Answer (score 0):

USE
update-grub

if you see
"Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
done
"
then edit your grub file using
nano  /etc/default/grub

locate and uncomment

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

if you dont find it then just add it save and run
update-grub